# How do I add a column to my dataframe that says what sheet name each row is from? Python

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, pandas

I am working with a Dataframe that has five sheets and I want to use four of them. So I can load it in:

`df = pd.read_excel('***.xls', sheet_name=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])`

But now I would like to add a column that says what sheet each row was in, and I am not sure how to do this. I tried something like this

```py
for name, frame in df.items():
        frame['Sheet'] = name
        df = df.append(frame, ignore_index=True)
```

but I was getting the following error:

> AttributeError: 'collections.OrderedDict' object has no attribute 'append'

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Let's say this is what my data looks like after I concat the sheets:

```py
df = pd.concat(pd.read_excel(***.xls, sheet_name=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
                          header=1), ignore_index=True, sort=False)
```

[Concat data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVro6.png)

My goal is to add a column that says what sheet each row was from, like so...

[Concat data with sheet name row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y5FUk.png)

Hopefully that helps you understand what I am trying to go for.

(Edit) I would also like to know how to do this if I wanted to use all the sheets in a dataframe, but didn't want to list the individual names of each sheet. Thanks!

Comment: Please share a example of your data and the output you expect.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

IIUC, try [`DataFrame.assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) in a [`list comprehension`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
sheets = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

df = pd.concat([pd.read_excel('***.xls', sheet_name=s)
                .assign(sheet_name=s) for s in sheets])
```

---

#### Update

If you want to use all sheets and assign a column of sheetname, you could do:

```
workbook = pd.ExcelFile('***.xls')
sheets = workbook.sheet_names

df = pd.concat([pd.read_excel(workbook, sheet_name=s)
                .assign(sheet_name=s) for s in sheets])
```

Comment: Would I be able to do something like this if I wanted to use all of the sheets in a file by saying sheet_name = None? I'd like to also be able to do this without having to list the sheet names.

Comment: @jpk yes, check updated answer for one potential way to do this

Comment: Thank you for the update! I just came to the same conclusion, nice to see that I was on the same page.

Answer (score 1):

If you specify `sheet_name` in the `read_excel` method, you will return an `ordered_dict` type object. And the `ordered_dict` object does not have the `append` function.You can try this,

```py
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_excel('***.xls', sheet_name=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])

df = pd.DataFrame()

for name, frame in data.items():
    frame['sheet'] = name
    df = df.append(frame)

print(df)
```

Comment: Thank you for helping! That worked for me as well, I just really liked the conciseness of the other solution.